# AdMob what purpose does the Publisher ID serve?

Tags: android, admob

What is the purpose of Publisher Id ?

Does it serve adverts to my app *from* that publisher id ?
Or does it serve random ads from the play store, and that should that be *my* publisher id ?

I have not been able to try it yet as I have no apps uploaded.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Publisher ID` servers as an `unique identifier` to your account so that whenever ads are clicked Admob knows `which account to credit` amount. Ads anyhow will be played at random which will be dependent upon the advertiser's budget and frequency.

You must `generate your unique Publisher ID` and put it in the app otherwise if you use any example from the internet it may lead to the benefit of another person.

*Good read:*

webpronews.com/google-explains-admob-publisher-and-mediation-ids-2012-04

basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/admob-tutorial-add-ads-to-your-application.7300/

Comment: THank you..Have my admob account..how is the crediting done ? have u any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Providing AdMob a publisher ID ties your app to your AdMob account. It tells AdMob which account to credit when an ad is clicked, and gives you reporting on that site placement.